# How to reset field in Acumatica WebDialogResult called by AskExt()?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am using a WebDialogResult defined on a SmartPanel by calling AskExt() that is used to prompt for a password.

Unfortunately, it caches the password that's entered, so it keeps pre-filling the dialog and I want it to be blank every time the dialog is called.

I've tried a variety of different things, such as calling with .AskExt(true), which is supposed to refresh the dialog and invoked .ClearDialog() before calling .AskExt(), and numerous other things including .Cache.Clear(), .Cache.ClearQueryCache(), .Reset(), .Update(new PwdFields()), .Delete(.Current) as well as the more direct .Current.Pwd = null and .Current.Pwd = "", but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the combination below consistently cleared the dialog of the password whenever it was re-displayed.

```
if (this.PasswordLookup1Status.AskExt(true) == WebDialogResult.OK)
{
    string currentPassword = this.PasswordLookup1Filter.Current.Pwd;
    this.PasswordLookup1Filter.Current.Pwd = "";
    this.PasswordLookup1Filter.Update(this.PasswordLookup1Filter.Current);
    if (currentPassword  == "1234")
    {
        Base.Transactions.Ask("Information", "Password [" + currentPassword  + "] is correct.", MessageButtons.OK);
        Base.Transactions.ClearDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new PXException("Password [" + currentPassword  + "] is incorrect.");
    }
    this.PasswordLookup1Filter.ClearDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is browser problem. In order to solve it I propose you to find id of control with help of firefox or chrome developer toolbar, and use javascript which will clean values.

Then you can add jquery like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#ctl00_phG_PXSPanelVerify2_PXFormViewVerify2_CustEdPwd2").focus()
    {
        $("#ctl00_phG_PXSPanelVerify2_PXFormViewVerify2_CustEdPwd2").text("");    
    }
});
```

Comment: I used IE and Inspect Element to locate the element, id="ctl00_phG_PXSPanelVerify2_PXFormViewVerify2_CustEdPwd2"
and added the jQuery code in the content, but it made no difference.

<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#ctl00_phG_PXSPanelVerify2_PXFormViewVerify2_CustEdPwd2").focus()
        {
            $("#ctl00_phG_PXSPanelVerify2_PXFormViewVerify2_CustEdPwd2").text("");
        }
    </script>
...

Comment: have you referenced jquery?

Comment: Yes, I had to add a reference to jQuery to the <head> section of the FormDetail.master page since that's the master for my page. I used Google. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: try please last modification

Comment: Very smart Yura, bit I had already wrapped it in the exact document ready function. I'm mostly not sure I'm placing that code in the correct location in the .aspx file. The only place I can see an alert("Document is ready"); call inside the document ready, is when I place it within the body of master page. When it is in the dependent .aspx file, nothing displays. Other Javascript code in Acumatica is typically placed immediately after the start of the content tag, and I've tried moving the code to all 3 of them on the page.

Comment: From my experience, if I placed js in master page, it wasn't able to find any control in dependent .aspx file. I used to place js before last     </asp:Content>